# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is not loading properly.

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, lts, gnu

My laptop is an acer Aspire e5-511

I completely erased windows 8 and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I'm having a couple of issues.

First is booting the o.s.  The first thing to appear is a gnu grub menu. I have to select advanced options for ubuntu to be load the o.s. then there are 3 versions with different numbers and three identical version but (recovery mode) Only one of them works every time.

Then command message or something appears that reads: 1.3845121 ACPI PCC probe failed.

I don't know why there are three versions and I dont understand why all this occurs because once I get in the system runs smoothly. It's annoying because I like things to work perfectly but clearly there is something wrong that I don't understand.

Also my laptop won't shut down at all unless I hold down the power button for 6 seconds. Otherwise the fan just keeps going round and it stays that way as if its trying to shut down but can't

I would be sincerely grateful for any help to find a solution and fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by an incompatibility with the Intel Atom SoCs. If you blacklist the "dw_dmac" module, the system should boot regularly. There are detailed instructions on how to do this if you search for "blacklist dw_dmac modprobe.d", add "grub", if you need to do it before loading the system.

Unfortunately, this fix seems to be not 100% reliable and you may still experience hibernation issues.

The Ubuntu version 12.04 should install and run without problems for you. If you do not need 14.04, that would be the safest route to take for now. However you may experience an issue with the brightness-function keys on your laptop, this can be solved as written in this guide: 
http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

Other than that, you may try to install 15.10 next thursday or the beta now and see if the new kernel works better with the N-processors.